# HTTP redirects to a page without HSTS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, hsts

I am using https://hstspreload.org to test the status of HTTP to HTTPS redirect and HSTS. I receive the following error message:

> HTTP redirects to a page without HSTS
>
> `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com/`, which does not serve a HSTS header that satisfies preload conditions.

Here are the contents of my `.htaccess` file:

```
###
# force HTTPS
###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

###
# HSTS
###
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
    Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>
```

From this [blog post](https://www.troyhunt.com/understanding-http-strict-transport/) I read that:

> ... that redirect must have the HSTS header, not the page it redirects to.

I am not sure what rules should I add or modify in order to fulfill this condition. If someone knows, based on the information I have provided, what ruling should I add or modify in my `.htaccess` file to have HSTS header in the redirect as well?

Comment: did you see the header `Strict-Transport-Security` of the https response? did you enable the module mod_headers and set `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: I see STS header when accessing the site via HTTPS, but I do not see STS header after the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. The `mod_headers` module is enabled.